# ID a gem/ST plugin: it shows a small popup when guard runs specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sublimetext2, guard

It is used in this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-intro-to-rails-screencast-i-wish-i-had--net-22191 at 18:18 in the upper right corner, it says 'RSpec results...'

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the [Growl](http://growl.info/) notifications in thew video. Please have a look at the [Guard wiki](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/System-notifications) for a list of possible notifications.